# Misplaced marginpar in twoside+twocolumn layout with pdfpages

Tags: double-sided, marginpar

`\includepdf` from the `pdfpages` package messes up the margin placement for this MWE:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper,twoside,twocolumn]{article}

\usepackage[outer=6cm,
        inner=2.5cm,
        top=2cm,
        marginparwidth=3cm,
        marginparsep=1mm,
        twoside=true
        ]{geometry}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{pdfpages}

\begin{document}

\includepdf{cover.pdf}

\lipsum
\marginpar{margin note}
\lipsum

\end{document}
```

where cover.pdf is a full one page pdf. What I mean by messing up is that the margin note is placed in the inner margin and not the outer one. I assume this is something along the lines of `\includepdf` not changing the odd/even counters correctly? Is there a better way to do what I am after?

Comment: `pdfpages` isn't necessary. I can reproduce the problem without it. Any marginpar on an odd page is affected.

Comment: I am guessing that the thought is that a marginal note in two column mode should appear in the margin of that column and not in the margin of the other column on the page.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From `marginnote` documentation:

> At double side layout (e.g. using class option twoside) \marginnote
>   needs to know the number of the current page to decide wether the page
>   is odd or even and so wether to use left or right margin. L A T E X
>   uses an asynchronous output. Because of this counter page should not
>   be used to get the number of the current page unless you are at page
>   head or foot. To solve the problem marginnote uses a mechanism similar
>   to labels. But this means, that the correct margin won’t be known at
>   this L A T E X run but only at the next. So after adding or deleting a
>   margin note or after each change of page break you need two L A T E X
>   runs to get all margins right.

The even and odd pages numbers are not properly fetched by the `marginpar` when `\includepdf` is used.

A possible solution will be to use `marginnote` package.

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper,twoside,twocolumn]{article}

\usepackage[outer=6cm,
        inner=2.5cm,
        top=2cm,
        marginparwidth=3cm,
        marginparsep=1mm,
        twoside=true
        ]{geometry}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage[fulladjust]{marginnote}

\begin{document}

\includepdf{pgfmanual.pdf}
\lipsum
\marginnote{margin note}
\lipsum

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Much obliged, works as advertised.

Comment: @phaebz Glad it helped :)